# How to balance classes in a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have 2 numpy arrays as follows:

**`images`** contains the names of image files (`images.shape` is (N, 3, 128, 128)):

`image_1.jpg
image_2.jpg
image_3.jpg
image_4.jpg`

**`labels`** contains the corresponding labels (0-3) (`labels.shape` is (N,)):

`1
1
3
2`

The issue I'm facing is that the classes are imbalanced, with class 3 >> 1 > 2 > 0.

I'd like to balance the final dataset by:

- counting the number of images (samples) in each class
- get the count of the class with lowest number of images
- use that count as the maximum number of images / labels for the other 3 classes
- randomly pop excess images / labels from the other 3 classes in `images` and `labels`

So far I'm using `Counter` to identify the number of images per class:

```
from Collections import Counter
import numpy as np

count = Counter(labels)
print(count)

>>>Counter({'1': 2991, '0': 2953, '2': 2510, '3': 2488})
```

How would you suggest I randomly pop matching elements from `images` and `labels` so they contain 2488 samples of classes 0, 1, and 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `np.random.choice` to create an integer-valued mask which you could apply to your labels and images to balance the dataset:

```
n = 2488

mask = np.hstack([np.random.choice(np.where(labels == l)[0], n, replace=False)
                      for l in np.unique(labels)])
```

Comment: would `ix` be a boolean vector that I'd apply to both arrays? (images and labels)

Comment: sorry my answer was wrong before, i've fixed it; `ix` is an integer vector that you use to index both arrays